# Connecting to MS Access Database from R (x64)

Tags: r, ms-access, 64-bit, odbc, windows-7-x64

I am trying to access my Access database using R. I have tried the below options but I am not able to connect to the database. I am using 64 bit R and 64 bit Access. I am using windows 7 also.. :(

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "E:/testdb.accdb"
myconn <-odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:/test.accdb")
con2 <- odbcConnect(db)
channel <- odbcConnectAccess("E:/testdb")
```

I always get the error. Please help me.

```
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=E:/testdb.accdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=E:/testdb.accdb") : ODBC connection failed
```

Comment: Could you add some system information? What operating system are you using, what version of Access and R (32 bit vs 64 bit for each)? In my experience, there are tricky  issues with ODBC connections in win7.

Comment: If you do `odbcDataSources()` in R, do you see the connection to your database? If not you will need to add it using the ODBC data sources tool in Windows.

Comment: I've come across this problem, it has been a super frustrating. I'm working with win7 64 and 32 bit access. I switched to 32 bit R and after lots of fidling around I finally got my DB to work using the following. `db<-file.path("yourDB.accdb")` `channel<-odbcConnectAccess2007(db)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is as error message suggests - you don't have **x64** Microsoft Access driver installed. Check it in Control panel - ODBC Data Sources (x64) on the Drivers tab. If it's not there, try to install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).